# Exporting data using fputcsv won't download

Tags: php, zend-framework2, export-to-csv

I am running across a very strange issue when trying to export data and download a CSV.

The problem is once I hit about 30 rows, the browser decides to display the data rather than download to a document. At first I thought it was the data, but during troubleshooting I tested by importing the same document.

Import it once and my download triggers and works perfect.  Import it again and duplicate the data, and all of a sudden it displays it instead of downloads it.

It's not a large file, but is there some sort of size or character limit that I can set?  I have tried troubleshooting a few ways, but not really sure where to go since it works until a certain limit.

```
    $group = "";
    ob_start();
    $group = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    fputcsv($group, array_keys(rest($groups[0])));
    foreach ($groups as $result) {
        fputcsv($group, $result);
    }
    fclose($group);
    return ob_get_clean();

    $response = $this->getResponse();
    $headers = $response->getHeaders();
    $headers->addHeaderLine('Content-Type', 'application/download');
    $headers->addHeaderLine('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
    $headers->addHeaderLine('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename=\"my_filen.csv\"");
    $headers->addHeaderLine('Accept-Ranges', 'bytes');
    $headers->addHeaderLine('Content-Length', strlen((string)$group));

    return $response;
```

If it helps at all, I am running Zend framework 2.

Comment: why bother with the accept-ranges, since your code doesn't actually DO byte-serving? plus, setting TWO content-types is pointless. the second is overwriting/replacing the first one. You're basically doing "this is a banana. this is a ferrari". `return ob_get_clean()` would terminat the code anyways, and execution would never reach the whole $headers business.

Comment: Thanks Marc, and your very much right.  There is a bunch of extra code in here as I was just trying to troubleshoot to see if something wasn't being read correctly, or made any changes.  Once I get it resolved I will definitely clean it up.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might have something to do with the flush settings in php.ini or gzip encoding.

You could fwrite it to a text file instead, and then force download of that file.

```
<?php
    $handle = fopen("somefile.txt", "w");
    fwrite($handle, "your content here");
    fclose($handle);

    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename('somefile.txt'));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize('somefile.txt'));
    readfile('somefile.txt');
    exit;
?>
```

Or if you can use it in your server:

```
$content = file_get_contents ($filename);
header ('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
echo $content;
```